# Postgres: how to use query in ST_TRANSLATE

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I want to give the ST_TRANSLATE function a geometry composed by

```sql
select st_astext(geom) from pieces where name='Large1'
```

This is apparently not possible though, but I do not understand why since the result of the previous query is `TRIANGLE((0 0,0.707106781186548 0,0 0.707106781186548,0 0))` so, doing something like:

```sql
select st_asewkt(
 st_translate(
   select st_asewkt(
     st_rotate(geom, -pi(), st_centroid(geom))) 
   from (
     select (
       select st_astext(geom) 
       from pieces where name='Large1') :: geometry as geom) as foo,
 0.707106781, 1.207106781)) as g;
```

should work, but it doesn't. The error I get is:

`LINE 1: select st_asewkt(st_translate(st_astext(select st_astext(geo...`

which gives the impression that I cannot use a query in ST_Translate.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to add an extra set of parentheses around the inner select(s)

```sql
SELECT st_translate((select ...),0.707106781, 1.207106781);
```

That being said, you could also work with geometries directly, there is no need to go back and forth between geometry and text.

You can also skip all the subqueries:

```sql
select st_asewkt(
  st_translate(
    st_rotate(geom, -pi(), st_centroid(geom)),
    0.707106781, 1.207106781)) 
  from pieces 
  where name='Large1';
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stuck on this since this morning and it's heartbreaking to see it was such a simple detail.